# How do I prompt with a msgbox VBA

Tags: vba

How do I prompt with a msgbox in VBA, when excel rows are changing to different letters.

For example if I have AAB in row1 and BBA in Row2, I need a prompt box after row1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small macro, it is set for column **C**

```
Sub DataCheck()
    Dim MyCol As String, rCheck As Range, r As Range
    MyCol = "C"
    Set rCheck = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range(MyCol & ":" & MyCol))

    For Each r In rCheck
    If r.Row = 1 Then
    Else
        If r.Text <> r.Offset(-1, 0).Text Then
            r.Select
            MsgBox "Data changed in row #" & r.Row
        End If
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This version of the code will detect changes in column **C** and insert a "spacer" row between them:

```
Sub DataCheck2()
    Dim MyCol As String, rCheck As Range, r As Range
    Dim rInsert As Range
    MyCol = "C"
    Set rCheck = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range(MyCol & ":" & MyCol))
    Set rInsert = Nothing

    For Each r In rCheck
        If r.Row = 1 Then
        Else
            If r.Text <> r.Offset(-1, 0).Text Then
                If rInsert Is Nothing Then
                    Set rInsert = r
                Else
                    Set rInsert = Union(rInsert, r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rInsert Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rInsert.EntireRow.Insert
    End If

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Instead of 
MsgBox "Data changed in row #" & r.Row 
I changed it to 
r.Insert.Row.Value = "Row Changed"
cause i want to insert row instead msgbox and want a text "row changed" in the row but kept on getting error. also its not recording lastrow were it changing value for ex. qwerty to new value, in column A i should have qwerty and "Row changed" in column C

Comment: hey do you have any suggestion for me..

Comment: Do you want to insert a new row just above the changed cell??

Comment: @user3795861  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thanks a lot and i did it different way first enter the row then the value but works either way.. once again thanks @Gary's Student